# IN operator between two lists is not working in oracle

Tags: oracle, where-clause, in-operator

When I use without IN operator as below its working

```
SELECT * FROM range_name_t where (cty_code_iso='CN' and lang_code_iso='zh');
```

But when I use IN operator as below getting ORA-00920: invalid relational operator error

```
SELECT * FROM range_name_t where ( cty_code_iso, lang_code_iso ) IN ( 'CN','zh' );

    ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
    00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
```

How to make it working above 2nd query?

Comment: Check with explain plan with and without in operator you might see different execution plans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables, but I have Scott's EMP to demonstrate it:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp
  3  where (deptno, job) in (select 10, 'CLERK' from dual);

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Oracle documentation of the `IN` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm):

> **in_conditions::=**
>
> [image: IN condition syntax]
>
> **expression_list::=**
>
> [image]
>
> If you use the upper form of the `in_condition` condition (with a single expression to the left of the operator), then you must use the upper form of `expression_list`. If you use the lower form of this condition (with multiple expressions to the left of the operator), then you must use the lower form of `expression_list`, and the expressions in each expression_list must match in number and datatype the expressions to the left of the operator.

You are using the "lower" version of the syntax and matching a tuple of values on the left-hand side of the `IN` condition; so the right-hand side must be a list of tuples and you need to use a second set of brackets (the outer brackets for the list and the inner brackets around each tuple in the list):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   range_name_t
where  ( cty_code_iso, lang_code_iso ) IN (( 'CN','zh' ));
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE range_name_t ( cty_code_iso, lang_code_iso ) AS
SELECT 'CN', 'zh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CN', 'ab' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IT', 'zh' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CTY_CODE_ISO | LANG_CODE_ISO
> :----------- | :------------
> CN           | zh
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f62cac35a37741e39a48d04b88bb3ac2)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM range_name_t
WHERE cty_code_iso IN ('CN') AND lang_code_iso IN ('zh');
```

I see nothing wrong with your leading example query. Is there a reason you have to use "IN"? All of the answers so far (including this one) walk a fine line between clever uses of "IN" and abusing "IN".